# How can I determine the index of the top item displayed in the drop-down list of a TComboBox?

Tags: c++, vcl, tcombobox, c++builder-10.4-sydney

How can I find the index of the top item in the drop-down list of a `TComboBox`?

I know that a `TListBox` has a `TopIndex` property, but I can't find anything similar to this for a `TComboBox`.

I'm using C++Builder in RAD Studio 10.4 Update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since FMX's `TListBox` does not have a `TopIndex` property, I'm going to assume you are referring to VCL instead.

In the VCL, you can access the `HWND` of the `TComboBox`'s drop-down ListBox by calling the Win32 [`GetComboBoxInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo) function on (or sending a [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-getcomboboxinfo) message to) the `HWND` returned by the `TComboBox::Handle` property. And then you can send an [`LB_GETTOPINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-gettopindex) message to the ListBox `HWND`.

```cpp
COMBOBOXINFO info = { sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO) };
GetComboBoxInfo(ComboBox1->Handle, &info);
// or: SendMessage(ComboBox1->Handle, CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO, 0, (LPARAM)&info);

int index = SendMessage(info.hwndList, LB_GETTOPINDEX, 0, 0);
```